# Rename [csr2] to [csr-racing-2]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

Can the tag for [csr2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csr2) be renamed to [csr-racing-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csr-racing-2)?

[The developer's website](http://www.naturalmotion.com/csr-racing-2) lists the game as *CSR Racing 2*, so a rename seems appropriate.

Comment: So its name is '[Custom Street Racing Racing 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/317548/28182)'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now done:

- [csr2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csr2) -> [csr-racing-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csr-racing-2)